# CheckboxList in datalist which has checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, datalist, checkboxlist

I want to do something like that in ASP.net C#

```
checkbox1         [checkbox_sub1 checkbox_sub2 checkbox_sub3]
checkbox2         [checkbox_sub1 checkbox_sub2 checkbox_sub3]
...
```

**Checkbox1** is an object list and the other checkboxes are stable for every row.

So,When **checkbox1** is not clicked the other checkboxes int the row should be **disabled**.
Is there any example of doing this.
I have lost more than 5 hours to find out something complete.

I tried so hard with datalist and inside checkbox list.but i didn't manage to succeed like that.I was messed with the code behind databound method!.

Any help or live example will be appreciated so much!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh God this is an easy answer, but in order to answer it, I would have to write the code for the entire solution. Can you provide what you have so far so at least we can go from there? This way, instead of answering it for you, I can *lead* you to the answer and you'll learn something too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple. do like this.

I have wrote a simple jQuery function like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".topic input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
       var is_checked=$(this).is(":checked");
       $(".inputs-list").find('input').prop("disabled",!is_checked);
    });

});
```

here is the complete [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/e8Nj3/40/)

Comment: Good one i want a little more help with C#

Comment: you want to do this in c# code. is that what you looking for